# Как добавить SurfaceView в XML-разметку

Tags: android

Есть класс  `GameActivity extends Activity`, в нем получаю экземпляр класса `SurfaceView` - `surf`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
surf = new GameSurface(this);
this.setContentView(surf); //  размещается на GameActivity
```

и есть файл разметки `gameactivity.xml`, в котором размещены кнопки управления.
 Если подключаю через метод `setContentView(R.layout.gameactivity)`, то отображается разметка, а прорисовка не идет.

Как сделать чтоб кнопки были внизу, а сверху было игровое поле?

Comment: Мой тебе совет, забей на SurfaceView. Я сделав пару игр на surface view и канвас очень разочарован. Просто жаль потраченного времени, на движок который тупит на половине устройств :) Лучше сразу используй libgdx или Ad engine ну или если уж совсем нативно хочется  - можно и openGLES освоить, для отрисовки 2d спрайтов там не так уж и много разбираться.

Comment: Ах да, еще ты упрешься в ограничение памяти на картинки используя Canvas и SurfaceView. Причем это ограничение очень близко, потому что все картинки придется держать в виде Bitmap в оперативке для отрисовки, ну т.е. это максимум на картинки пара мегабайт в png. А в OpenGL, libgdx и adengine  ты уже будешь использовать атласы загруженные в память видеоадаптера. Т.е. не будешь тратить оперативку и объем для изображений будет значительно больше.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно указать место для вашего класса-наследника `SurfaceView`(GameSurface) на общей XML-разметке активити (`gameactivity.xml`), а не подключать его отдельно.
Этот класс обязательно должен содержать конструктор с аттрибутами, а на разметке указывается полный путь до вашего класса (включающий имя пакета)

```
package myapp.views; // имя пакета класса-наследника SurfaceView

public MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

 //конструктор без атрибутов
public MySurfaceView(Context context) { 
super(context);
 ...
}

 //обязателен конструктор с атрибутами
public MySurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) { 
super(context, attributeSet);
getHolder().addCallback(this);
 ...
}
 ...
}
```

В вашей разметке (`gameactivity.xml`) определяете местоположение своего `SurfaceView` с указанием полного пути до класса:

```
<myapp.views.MySurfaceView
  android:id = "@+id/mySurfaceView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Получить доступ к `SurfaceView` из активити можно методом `findViewById()`:

```
SurfaceView mySurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
```

[пример](http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-1-surface.html)

PS: ваш `surf` не метод, а экземпляр класса